# Extra padding in position: absolute property

Tags: html, css, css-position

In the following code, there is padding on the left `div` block navigation area with fixed (or absolute) position on the top of the `div` block looking like 1em but no padding on the left in comparison with no padding on another `div` content block having no top or left padding. This is true in at least Firefox and Chrome. How can I get no padding on the `position: absolute` block. Note: This problem disappears if I delete `position: absolute`. How can I fix it? I know I'll want padding later, but I want the padding to look right on the nav AND content area and I would like them to look the same with NO padding as a baseline.

Here's an image. See how the have area on the left is thicker and the content area on the left is thin?

[image]

Here is example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {
    background: #fff;
    }
    div.content {
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 20em;
    margin-right: 4em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    }
    p {
    color: #fff;
    }
    div.nav {
    background: #000;
    width: 16em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    border-radius: 2em
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <p>This is content area text</p>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <p>This is a nav area text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aSS6/) of your code, and there doesn't seem to be any padding on the left div.  Are you sure that padding isn't coming from somewhere else?

Comment: The above is the entire code making the web page. I copied it in directly from the file (after adding the 4 code spacings).

Comment: I wrote another, simpler one and it did the same thing, but not in jsFiddle. @Moose, could you do me a favor and try the code loaded into Firefox from a file? Thanks. I did it on a completely different computer, and it does the same.

Comment: I did some other messing around. Doesn't matter if I put the style in a css file and link it. If I use `h1` for the block, it doesn't have the padding any longer. Only does it with `div` as the styled container.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer here http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3083754.htm

It needs a `* {margin:0; padding:0}` added to the beginning and it works right.

Answer (score -1):

if you are assigning position: absoloute; to any element, then do not apply the margin property. take advantage of top, left, right, bottom property.

Comment: In the code above, there is no margin property for the `div` element that has `position:absolute;` , which uses `top` and `left` property in relation to `position`. The only place where there is margin is the class content `div` which is working correctly.